# Getting error on New-AzureRmDataFactoryPipeline using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure, pipeline, azure-data-factory, runbook

I am trying to run [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/v1/data-factory-build-your-first-pipeline-using-powershell#create-pipeline) on my Local Machine Using PowerShell, but at this line `New-AzureRmDataFactoryPipeline $df -File .\MyFirstPipelinePSH.json` (when I want to create Pipeline) I will get this error:

```
New-AzureRmDataFactoryPipeline : Exception of type 'Microsoft.Azure.Commands.DataFactories.ProvisioningFailedException' 

was thrown.

At line:295 char:17

+ ... $pipeline = New-AzureRmDataFactoryPipeline $df -File $temp_jsonFilePa ...

+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureRmDataFactoryPipeline], ProvisioningFailedException

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.DataFactories.NewAzureDataFactoryPipelineCommand
```

in next step of tutorial I should run `Get-AzureRmDataFactorySlice $df -DatasetName AzureBlobOutput -StartDateTime 2017-07-01` that the result is shown bellow and it will show `State` is `None`:

```
ResourceGroupName : TestResourceGroup2
DataFactoryName   : RezaDataFactory
DatasetName       : AzureBlobOutput
Start             : 7/1/2017 12:00:00 AM
End               : 8/1/2017 12:00:00 AM
RetryCount        : 0
State             : None
SubState          : 
LatencyStatus     : 
LongRetryCount    : 0
```

Can you please guide me how I should solve the problem?

there is also a solution [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6b0b5d80-602a-4cc1-9b0d-70f031435367/error-message-when-creating-new-pipeline?forum=AzureDataFactory) that I can't understand what it mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are creating linked Storage services, you should pass storage `username` and storage `ConnectionString`. make sure that you are passing these two parameters truly. then, if it dosn't solve the problem, delete the resource (or change your resource) and create it again. it will solve the problem.